# Communauté de Brasseurs Amateurs Française (Community of French Amateur Brewers)

Tags: brewing

Bonjour,

Je débute complètement dans le brassage maison et je cherche une Communauté de Brasseurs Amateurs.(I am completely new to the idea of home brewing and am looking for a **Community of Amateur Brewers for French speaking individuals**).

Any information would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you kindly add a English Translation ?

Comment: I made an English translation. Could the OP please verify that this is what the translation should be.

Comment: Are you looking for an online Community or a local physical community? If it is local organization you are seeking, which area are you from?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is a very good beer shop/store called [Cave à Bulles](http://www.bieremasterclass.fr/lieu/) at 45 rue Quincampoix in Paris; it is in the 4th arrondissement, near the Pompidou Centre. Here there is a community you can join where the discussion is all about French craft beer and amateur brewing. They have regular *degustation* (tasting) sessions and an online discussion forum, although it is not in any sense a large commercial operation - in other words perfect for amateurs interested in beer and the brewing process.

I was a member of this group when I lived in Paris some years ago, and I know it is still going.

Comment: I live in North of France and i just find a very good shop : At Home Bière , near Lille !

Answer (score 0):

If in Quebec or even Canada for that matter you may wish to check out the [Montre Alers](http://www.montrealers.ca/accueil/) (Club de Brasseurs/Homebrewing Club). This club is centered around the area of Montreal, Quebec.

> The Montre Alers is an organization composed of Montreal-area home brewers who share both a passion for the hobby of home brewing and a desire to see it grow and flourish. Our main activities consist of monthly tasting meetings, competitions, and discussing various brewing-related topics online.

Comment: Hello, about Canada, just find this Excellent youtube channel : https://www.youtube.com/user/decapsule

Answer (score 0):

My wife speaks French and has is a very good Brewster in her own right, she has found these:

http://www.brassageamateur.com/forum/

http://univers-biere.net/liens_brassam.php

I hope they are what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in Paris, you might also want to check out [Brew Unique](http://www.brewunique.com/). You can learn how to brew there, get supplies, but Mike and the rest of the staff will also be happy to help you analyze your homebrewed beer if you stop by with a bottle, and to give you tips. I run into other homebrewers every time I stop by.